# How "${var-Apple}", "${var+Apple}", "${var=Apple}" work?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, operating-system

Let's say that var=Banana and Apple is a sequence of characters. I know the output of these commands, but I don't understand why they are working as they do.
The output for echo `${var-Apple}` is Banana, for `${var+Apple}` is Apple and for `${var=Apple}` is Banana, but why?

Also, when I have the command echo `${var-Apple} | ${VAR-Pear}` and VAR doesn't exist, it will print Banana | Pear? It will also print Pear if we put = instead of - and it will print nothing if we put +.

Answer (score 1):

These constructs are described in `man bash` under *Parameter Expansion*.

> ${parameter:-word}
> Use **Default Values**.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word  is  substituted.  Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.
>
> ${parameter:=word}
> Assign  **Default  Values**.   If  parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is assigned to parameter.  The value of parameter  is  then  substituted.   Positional parameters and special parameters may not be assigned to in this way.
>
> ${parameter:+word}
> Use **Alternate Value**.  If parameter is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of word is substituted.

It's hard to find them directly as they use the colon variant, but there's an explanation:

> [...] bash tests  for  a  parameter that is unset or null. Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset.

Note that `echo "${VAR=Pear}"` changes the value of `$VAR` if <strike>it's empty</strike> the variable is unset.